# Denote a function given certain conditions.

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function:
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x & \forall x\leq0\\
x^{2} & \forall x>0
\end{cases}$

Is it mathematically correct to write the same function as follows:

$f(x|x\leq0)=x$ and $f(x|x>0)=x^2$?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in creating your own notation as long as you explain what it means and doesn't create a confusion with other notations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Comment: If it helped you, may you accept it? :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the notation you suggest is not standard. Possibly, it isn't used either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!!